# Send object to specific partition with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

Suppose I have a RDD with nPartitions partitions, and I'm using the mapPartitionsWithIndex method, while also keeping on the driver an array x of dimension nPartitions. 
Now suppose I would like to ship x(i) to partition i so that it may work on it, a naïve way to do so would be to just call x(i) in the closure, as in the following toy example :

```
val sc = new SparkContext() 
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).repartition(10)
val nPartitions = rdd.partitions.length 
val myArray = Array.fill(nPartitions)(math.random) //array to be shipped to executors
val result = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index,data) => 
  Seq(data.map(_ * myArray(index)).sum).iterator 
)
```

(Ignore the logic within mapPartitionsWithIndex, only the myArray(index) is what interests us.
However if my understanding is correct, this will ship the entire array myArray to all executors, as the array is in the closure. Now if we suppose the array contains large objects which may take up too much memory / serialization time, this becomes a problem.

Is there a way to avoid this, and to ship only the components of the array corresponding to the partitions within a given executor ?

Comment: Ulysse, did you manage to optimize the partitions shipped data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of premature optimization. Sending an array as big as the number of partitions is not going to save you much vs sending just the value for the partition, if at all possible.

However, instead of sending the array as a closure, you should send the array as a
broadcast variable: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

The main difference is that the closure is serialized and sent out for each task, while, from the doc page "Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks".

Comment: This is not a case of premature optimization, as the arrays I am shipping do not contain Ints but large objects. For a 100 machine cluster, this means dividing serialization and memory costs by 100, which is a lot. Plus, my array will only be shipped once, and is not meant to be read-only. This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the requirement about large objects since it was at the very end. How large are objects, and how are they stored ? One way would be to sore them in n directories in HDFS and have each partition pull them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sending large objects to partitions, but an inverted approach would be to use mapPartition in conjunction with partitioning by columns. Namely, using mapPartition in this fashion would be pulling in the large object on a per partition level vs. on a per row level.